# Запись данных из форм в БД

Tags: php, html

имеется форма и требуется после отправки добавлять эти данные в БД, и в случаи если такие данные были в бд, провести автозаполнение в ячейках

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = " INSERT INTO pins1(name,fio,code) VALUES('".$_POST['name'."','".$_POST['fio']."','".$_POST['code'."')";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); 

$query = "select * from pins1";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); 

if($result)
{
    echo "Выполнение запроса прошло успешно";

     $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); // количество полученных строк
     
    echo "<table><tr><th>name</th><th>fio</th><th>code</th></tr>";
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rows ; ++$i)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<tr>";
            for ($j = 0 ; $j < 3; ++$j) echo "<td>$row[$j]</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

дальше можно разобраться! с if-else поиграйтесь

Comment: Спасибо! Я просто новичок в PHP и БД :)